# How to specify where homerserver.yaml should be saved when running initial generate on synapse docker?

Tags: docker, nas, synology, matrix-synapse

I am trying to get a Matrix Synapse server running on my Synology NAS through docker.

When I run the `generate` command to get the intial homeserver.yaml, it does get generated :

> $ sudo docker run -it --rm     --mount type=volume,src=synapse-config,dst=/data     -e SYNAPSE_SERVER_NAME=my.matrix.host -e SYNAPSE_REPORT_STATS=yes matrixdotorg/synapse:latest generate

```
Creating log config /data/my.matrix.host.log.config
Generating config file /data/homeserver.yaml
Generating signing key file /data/my.matrix.host.signing.key
A config file has been generated in '/data/homeserver.yaml' for server name 'my.matrix.host'. Please review this file and customise it to your needs.
```

So the file is generated in `/volume1/@docker/volumes/synapse-config/_data` but I don't know how to actually access this folder.

How can I specify within the `docker generate` command where I would like the `/data` data to reside ? I have created a folder (/volume1/synapse/data) to that effect but I don't know how to make sure the output of the `docker generate`  actually goes there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your `--mount` you sepcify what should be mapped to /data within the container.

Use e.g. `-v /volume1/synapse/data:/data` instead to map it to some directory on the host filesystem.

Comment: I am donating to SO right now ! Thank you it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The image you are trying to use supports this environment variable, according to the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/matrixdotorg/synapse/):

```
`SYNAPSE_CONFIG_PATH`: path to the file to be generated. Defaults to <SYNAPSE_CONFIG_DIR>/homeserver.yaml
```

To inject this ENV, add  `-e SYNAPSE_SERVER_NAME=<desired-path>` in your `docker run` command

Comment: Yes I tried that but for some reaon it does not recognize my folder `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/volume1/Matrix/synapse/config'`. I am positive this folder exists